# One-Liner with Return Statement

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to write the JavaScript code below as a one-liner?

```
this.isContactPage = (window.location.pathname === '/contact');
if (!this.isContactPage) return false;
```

The method continues on if `this.isContactPage` is true.

The property `this.isContactPage` is needed in other places in the script.

Comment: if `this.isContactPage` is `false`. what should be returned?

Comment: Oops forgot the `!`. The method continues on if the condition is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll be fairly dense and "obscured" code, but you can inline assignments in conditionals:

```
if ( !this.isContactPage = ( window.location.pathname == '/contact' ) ) return false;
```

This will only return the function if `this.isContactPage` is assigned the value `false` otherwise the function is not returned and continues on execution, as opposed to:

```
return ( this.isContactPage = ( window.location.pathname == '/contact' ) );
```

Which will return `true` or `false` immediately.

Comment: I like it; a little dense as you say, but still better than splitting over two lines IMO.

Comment: Actually, does this work for you? JS Bin and JSFiddle seem confused: http://jsbin.com/qonecoboje/1/edit

Comment: In your jsbin you forgot to include jQuery, and wrap your code in a page-ready function. See this edit: http://jsbin.com/puwuvajuda/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 5):

```
return !(this.isContactPage = (window.location.pathname === '/contact'));
```

Another example:

```
console.log(window.prop); // undefined
console.log(!(window.prop = true) || undefined); // undefined
console.log(!(window.prop = true)); // false
console.log(window.prop); // true
```

Comment: Doesn't this one differ in behavior from the OP, though? The OP only return if `this.isContactPage` is assigned `true`. This returns either way.

Comment: I've just editted and added this example: `console.log(!(window.prop = true) || undefined);` just for that case..

Comment: @BrianNorth: yes that's correct; I forgot to mention that in my question, will edit now

Comment: @cantera - You want a one liner that may return in some case and may not return in another? I don't know a way to do something like that..

Answer (score 1):

`return !this.isContactPage = (window.location.pathname === '/contact')`

Answer (score 1):

with this you will not have errors!

```
this.isContactPage = /contact/gi.test(window.location.pathname);
if (!this.isContactPage) return false;
```

or

```
return !(/contact/gi.test(window.location.pathname))
```

Comment: Interesting, hadn't thought to use a regex

Comment: A more accurate regex would be `/^\/contact$/i` - otherwise it would test positive for any pathname that includes the word "contact" regardless of where it is.

Answer (score 1):

I have something makes your code as short as possible!

```
return !(this.isContactPage=location.pathname=='/contact')
```

1. You don't need "Window"
2. You don't need returning false or true directly through your code
3. You don't need ===, then change it to ==
   The shortest way guys suggested has 88 letters and this suggestion has just 68 letter and is more readable and understandable!

Comment: Thx for responding - had no idea `window` was optional. Confirmed here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location